# Does the Bing Maps for iOS allow for driving directions?

Tags: iphone, ios, bing-maps

Context: The 'Maps' application on iOS has a URL Scheme to that allows applications to plot out driving directions for a given set of points.

Question: Does the Bing Maps iOS Control or Bing Maps iOS App have some sort of private or undocumented APIs that would allow me to provide the user with a driving directions given a set of pre-defined points or addresses? Either via the SDK or via URL scheme.

I checked the Bing Maps iOS Control headers and documentation and could not find anything publicly defined.

Also, I'm well aware that the app / sdk could break this interface at any given time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few months old, but I'll provide an answer:

After numerous hours spent inducing headaches, I can confidently, and sadly, say no. All you see in the public documentation is what's there.